# How to interpret HTML as plain Text inside textarea?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make a online code editor, so that I don't have to upload modified files to the website each time. To edit the contents of a file, the code gets its contents and puts them into a textarea in form of text like this:

```
<textarea id="text" name="contents">
<?php 
    include_once "useful.php";
    if(isset($_GET["url"])){
        echo file_get_contents($_GET["url"]);
    } 
?>
</textarea>
```

The Problem is the following:

If the file has a `</textarea>` tag inside, this closes my textarea tag closes without displaying the entire file.

Is there a simple solution to solve this? Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Try with `htmlspecialchars` function if it solves for you.

Comment: @tilz0R thanks for your reply. The problem is that I want to display the file exactly as it is saved on the drive.

Comment: So my comment didn't solve problem?

Comment: btw textarea interpret html inside it as a plain text

Comment: @Dherya yes it does, except of `</textarea>` which indicates when this tag should be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`htmlspecialchars` function will solve your problem.

This code does what you want:

```
<textarea>
<?php
    //Fake file content
    $fileContent = "</textarea> with something";
    print htmlspecialchars($fileContent);
?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: Wow, this actually works. [MyExample](http://andihamolli.tk/oe/test.php). I was reading this [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) and it says this `<?php
$new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
echo $new; // &lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;
?>` so i thought this wouldn't work

Comment: It actually will.

Comment: Thank you! I'm turning the favour

Answer (score 0):

`html_entity_decode()` and some bracket conversion enabled me to display the HTML code `<textarea></textarea>` *within* a `<textarea>` block.

This is my first reply here, so please be kind. :)

I had to fix a PHP text file editor which would output its file contents within a `<textarea></textarea>` window -- however, if the file it reads *contained* `<textarea></textarea>` blocks, the output window would close the block and interpret it as HTML and the closing `</textarea>` and the rest of the file would not be displayed in the editor window.

(In other words, it is a PHP script which loads files and displays their contents inside of a `<textarea></textarea>` window for editing, etc.)

i.e. a file contained:

`Enter stuff here: <textarea name="blah"></textarea> Yay Stuff.`

it displayed as:

`Enter stuff here: <textarea name="blah">` (missing all other content!)

There were two types of interpretation needed.

For a **PHP** file:

After beating myself up and with some help from this site, I was able to trick the interpreter by 'sanitizing' the block by first converting the ending `</textarea>` to `&lt/textarea&gt`.

ex:
($Body is just the contents of the file to display in the editor)

```
//if reading a <textarea block of code
if (preg_match("%<textarea%/i",$Body)) {

  //turn < > into &lt &gt for the end of textarea block
  $Body=preg_replace("%</textarea>%/i","&lt/textarea&gt", $Body);

  //sanitize (this is the output window where the file content goes)
  print html_entity_decode("</font><textarea>" .$Body. "</textarea>\n");
}
```

This allowed the window to correctly output the file content such as:

`Enter stuff here: <textarea name="blah"></textarea>` Yay stuff.

For a **non-PHP** file (like HTML):

You have to search for the `</textarea>` and can just use `".$Body."`

i.e.

```
$filetype=pathinfo($File);
$filetype['extension'];
$php_files=Array('php','php3','php5');
if (!in_array($filetype['extension'], $php_files)) {  

$Body=preg_replace("%</textarea>%/i","&lt/textarea&gt", $Body);
  echo "</font><textarea> ".$Body." </textarea>\n";  
}
```

Note: If a PHP file did -not- contain a `<textarea>` it would be fine to use: 
    `print html_entity_decode($Body)` and I did have to contend for that as well.

Note2:
I am displaying PHP 5+ code, but I had to do this for PHP 5, and just FYI it works fine with eregi() and eregi_replace()

It drove me mad, so I hope this helps someone else.
...mad enough that I came back again and updated my answer. :)

Comment: Yes, except that `html_entities_decode()` does the opposite... you need `htmlentities()` to convert characters from < to &lt;

Comment: I clarified the uses. It is different if the file being read is HTML with PHP, PHP with HTML (using `<textarea>`), or PHP with HTML (without `<textarea>`.

`htmlentities()` only worked if the file being read into $Body was a non-PHP file -- otherwise I had to use `html_entities_decode()`.

Comment: I know it's old, but I updated my answer - for non-PHP/HTML files, I used just `".$Body."`